# AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'Aqtau'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, getattr, getattribute

I work with django first time. And fced with this error. Can You help me to solve. Erro like this, I have many models and data in there, and I put this data to html like table, after I want to change values in data, but in views I cant search my models

My models py like this: (in city_name I put name of Model there it is Aqtau )

```
from django.db import models
class Aqtau(models.Model):
  city_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  KT_by_projects_10g = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  KT_by_projects_100g = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  KT_on_facts_10g = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  KT_on_facts_100g = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

My views to put data to html:

```
def index(request):
  Aqtau_city = Aqtau.objects.all().values()
  template = loader.get_template('index.html')
  context = {
    'Aqtau_city': Aqtau_city,
  }
  return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

HTML looks like:

```
<tr>
  {% for x in Aqtau_city %}
  <td>Aqtau</td>
  <td>{{ x.KT_by_projects_10g }} </td>
  <td>{{ x.KT_by_projects_100g }} </td>
  <td>{{ x.KT_on_facts_10g }} </td>
  <td>{{ x.KT_on_facts_100g }} </td>

  <td><a href="update/{{ x.city_name }}/{{ x.id }}">update</a></td>

  {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

urls.py looks like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('update/<str:city_name>/<int:id>', views.update, name='update'),
```

And views update like: There i want to get model by getattr, but django db.models don't search Aqtau class.

```
def update(request, city_name, id):
  model = getattr(models, city_name)
  mymember = model.objects.get(id=id)
  template = loader.get_template('update.html')
  context = {
    'mymember': mymember,
  }
  return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Error like this
model = getattr(models, city_name)
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'Aqtau'

Comment: Please *don't*. This is a security vulnerability: it can result in fetching for example user credentials, sensitive data, tokens, etc.

Comment: Your `getattr` is pointed at the `django.db.model` module which doesn't have your actual model in it - if you want to dynamically get models then you can use `get_models()` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/applications/#methods

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using this method getattr
personally, I'm using the get_object_or_404 function in the update method it's will throw a 404 exception if the model not found

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def update(request, city_name, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Aqtau, id=id)
    context = {
        "object": obj
    }
    return render(request, "update.html", context)
```

Note you should include the model form class in the update method to draw the form of model attributes you can see full documentation in this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your model into your view.py file instead of using getattr(models, city_name)

something like this:

```
from apps.city_app.models import Aqtau
```

After that, you will be able to get objects of that model,
something like the below:

```
mymember = Aqtau.objects.get(id=id)
```

Also I suggest to use 'get_object_or_404' for you fetching,Because it will prevent form DoesNotExist Error:

```
mymember = get_object_or_404(Aqtau, id=id)
```

If you wanted to use 'get_object_or_404' you can import it like below:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
```